# How to use a Table to generate numerical data from tridimensional scalar or vector function?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, numerical-value

I am interested to generate numerical values for a scalar and vector function (both are complex functions).

My question and concern are how is possible to evaluate if the functions have three coordinates (variables). I mean to obtain a numerical  Table of two values [x, y] or [x,y,z] numerical data and after be able to plot them.

Here, is the code but the implementation is incorrect,  Please run the code

```
Clear["Global`*"];  

L = 15; step = 0.5; (*size grid and numerical step*) 
gh = Sin[ x +    0.5  y  + 5  z]  + Exp[I 2 x + I y + I 0.5 z]

gradf = Grad[gh, {x, y, z}]

data1 = Table[gh /. { y -> 0,  z -> 0}, {x, -L, L, step}] 

data2 = Table[gradf /. { y -> 0,  z -> 0}, {x, -L, L, step}]

data3 = Table[Norm[gradf /. { y -> 0,  z -> 0}], {x, -L, L, step}]
```

Of course, the data can be generated forcing the problem, after using and defining two variables as zero, but they are tridimensional functions and they are not one-dimensional function?

Comment: Why not make `gh` and `gradf` functions instead of expressions with `gh[x_, y_, z_] := ...`?

Comment: @lirtosiast, Yes I  already used this form you mention, but it does not work properly also this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the question. "but the implementation is incorrect" -- Please explain what exactly what makes you think so.

Answer (score 1):

@lirtosiast's comment shows the right way to solve your problem:

```
gh[x_, y_, z_] :=Sin[x + 0.5 y + 5 z] + Exp[I 2 x + I y + I 0.5 z] //Evaluate

gradf[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[gh[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

data1 = Table[gh[x, 0, 0] , {x, -L, L, step}];
(* {5.28257, 3.30335, 2.47209,,...}*)

data2 = Table[gradf[x, 0, 0]   , {x, -L, L, step}]  
(* {-2.73575 + 0.308503 I, -1.36788 + 0.154251 I,-4.29246 +0.0771257 I}, {-1.68219 - 1.49612 I, -0.841096 -0.748058 I, -2.10644 - 0.374029 I},...}*)

data3 = Table[Norm@gradf[x, 0, 0]   , {x, -L, L,step}] 
(*{5.28257, 3.30335, 2.47209,,...}*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is the problem still remains because the function (scalar or vector) depends on [x, y, z] in the output is only a function of x. The data is generated imposing the condition  [x,0,0].  The question is if there any way to generate a uniform grid (mesh grid) for all variables [x,y,z] at the same time and generate a numerical table? The main aim is to sample numerically a function scalar or vector using Mathematica.

Comment: @irondonio `Table[gh[x, y, z], {x, -L, L, step}, {y, -L, L, step}, {z, -L, L, 
  step}]`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @MelaGo. These codes can generate a Table. but I expect to have a Table with a single numeric value after evaluating numerically a scalar function,  Any comment about how can it be implemented?

Comment: @irondonio I'm not sure exactly what you mean. You do get a single value (though a complex one). You can flatten the table with `Flatten`...

Comment: Thanks, @MelaGo, sorry for the confusion,  I mean a single value, after the evaluation of the function f[x,y,z], in the case of the complex function, should be the norm as in the vector case. The point is the output should be represented as a pair of numbers [x,f[x,y,z]] where f[x,y,z] were previously evaluated and represent a simple real value